# Understanding this code to generate a watermark logo for an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, watermark

```
% imgew: watermark image  
% imge1: Orginal imge  

function W=dmg(imgew,imge1);      
% obtain original and watermark image

[w h]=size(imgew');  
[w1 h1]=size(imge1');  
a=1;  
b=1;  
W=zeros(size(imge1'));  

for i=1:w:w1  
for j=1:h:h1  
    W(i:a*w,j:b*h)=imgew';  
    b=b+1;  
end  
a=a+1;  
b=1;  
end  

W=W';
```

Comment: What parts specifically are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: i cant seem to understand that what happens when it goes in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The nested loops simply computes a mosaic 'W' of 'imgew' images. Note that the size of 'W' will be equal to *or larger* than 'imge1'.